# Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"VpcSecurityGroupIds\

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to run `restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot` in aws lambda with python runtime 3.6.

It throws an exception:

> Unknown parameter in input: "VpcSecurityGroupIds", must be one of:
>   DBInstanceIdentifier, DBSnapshotIdentifier, DBInstanceClass, Port,
>   AvailabilityZone, DBSubnetGroupName, MultiAZ, PubliclyAccessible,
>   AutoMinorVersionUpgrade, LicenseModel, DBName, Engine, Iops,
>   OptionGroupName, Tags, StorageType, TdeCredentialArn,
>   TdeCredentialPassword, Domain, CopyTagsToSnapshot, DomainIAMRoleName,
>   EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication, EnableCloudwatchLogsExports,
>   ProcessorFeatures, UseDefaultProcessorFeatures: ParamValidationError
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the versions of boto3 in AWS lambda are

```
boto3: 1.9.42
botocore: 1.12.42
```

They do not support the parameter `VpcSecurityGroupIds`.

I need to issue a `modify_db_instance` call after `restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot` to fix the setting.